# prev() not returning div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm probably being especially dense about this, but I can't get an element to return using prev(). My basic HTML structure is:

```
<div>
   <table></table>
</div>
<input type="button">
```

Where when I press the button, I want to get the previous element (the div element). To achieve this my button has a function attached to it with

```
var nearestDiv = $(this).prev();
```

When I've checked the contents of nearestDiv in the console it appears to be some kind of JQuery object rather than a HTML div. I've tried popping .val() at the end of .prev() but this comes back empty. How can I get the div element?

Note that my button is generated on the fly and doesn't have anything which identifies it.

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Comment: p/s: `.val()` chained to the end of `.prev()` will not work because the selector has moved on to the previous element, and is no longer at the input element. No elements other than input has `value`.

Comment: When you use $(this), think about the jQuery selector you have for the function. Is it properly selecting <input type='button'>? If so, then $(this) will work.

Comment: Well prev() returns a jQuery object with the element in it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use jquery `get` function, to get a native html object and not the jquery wrapper:

```js
$("input").on("click",function(){
  console.log("jquery wrapper:",$(this).prev());
  console.log("native html div object:",$(this).prev().get(0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <table></table>
</div>
<input type="button">
```

Comment: Putting .get(0) at the end of prev() returned the html div I was after - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your html structure is same as you provided in the question, it will definitely return the div element. Note that there is no `val()` method for div element, you need to either use `.html()` or `.text()` inorder to get the contents.

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function () {
    var div = $(this).prev();
    alert(div.html());
    alert(div.text());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/88/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to give `.text()` or `.html()` for standard HTML Elements. So your code should be:

```
var nearestDiv = $(this).prev().html();
var nearestDiv = $(this).prev().text();
```